# CSS - edit circle with multiline

Tags: html, css, geometry, multiline

I have a circle but it works only with one line of text. When I try to have a second line then text will jump down. How can I edit my circle to have second lines? The answer in jsFiddle would be best.

Here is what I have (my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apujcjd4/)):

```
<table>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #f5f5f5;">
        <div class="circle"><strong> 1.500</strong>  <sup>Eur</sup>
            <br>month</div>
    </td>
</table>

.circle {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#293a42;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle strong {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.circle sup {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by reducing the line-height and using padding to position your text like this:

```
.circle {
    width:100px;
    height:68px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:red;
    line-height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#293a42;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:32px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
you can do this by removing the line-height and update your css like the below code:


The CSS:

<!-- language: lang-css -->
    .circle {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #293a42;
        border-radius: 50px;
        color: red;
        display: table-cell;
        font-size: 14px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100px;
    }
<!-- end snippet -->
```

[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apujcjd4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over [this answer](https://codepen.io/JLHwung/pen/yoYogo) and find it very pretty:

```
.circle {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

It needs [flex](https://caniuse.com/flexbox) however.